# Create a new vector from original one, by taking every `t_thin` entries after the first `t_b` entries

Tags: r

Given a vector `y` of length `t_b+t_s`, I would like to create a new vector by taking every `t_thin` entries after the first `t_b` entries. What would be most simple and efficient? My current way is:

```
y_new = c()
for (i in 0:(t_s/t_thin-1)) { 
y_new = cbind(y_new, y[i*t_thin + t_b])
}
```

which seems terrirble. Thanks!

Comment: this would return the values of y between t_b and t_b+t_thin : y[t_b:(t_b+t_thin)]

Comment: What is the correct way then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you have two sets of indices:

1 to t_b and t_b to end, every t_thin entries

So subset y to these indices:

```
y[ c(1:t_b, seq(t_b+t_thin,length(y),t_thin)) ]
```

Comment: +1, but I'm not sure if they want the `1:t_b` part included or not.